# Is it possible to dynamically update html on build using webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am creating a photography portfolio, and I would like the html to contain a list with one list item for each album, like this:

```
 <ul class="content-area__list">
<ls class="content-area__album-title">cat album</ls>
<ls class="content-area__album-title">dog album</ls>
            </ul>
```

I would like to generate this content while compiling using webpack, using keys from an object in a javascript file. The file looks like:

```
class AlbumList {
constructor() {
this.list = 
{'cat album': ['cat-photo.jpg', 'meow.jpg', 'paws.jpg'], 
'dog album': ['woof.jpg', 'tail-wag.jpg']} 
} }
export default AlbumList
```

I am able to generate the html when loading the site, but since the list will only change before compiling I would rather not make the user's browser generate the list. Also I am attaching event listeners to each list item from a different module than the one that creates the list items, so it would be easier if the html file already contains the list items.  Please let me know if this is possible, or if there is a better way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: You will need a templating language for this. HTML alone isn't going to work, unless you have some sort of plugin that does a find and replace sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had looked into making an HTML template, but I wasn't able to find a way to create one list item for each album name, as there could be any number of albums. In javascript I would do this using Object.keys() and .forEach. I will keep looking, please let me know if you are able to point me in the right direction.

edit: and after writing this I think I found my answer:
https://dev.to/pldg/build-a-simple-static-site-generator-with-webpack-5a29